# How to merge SSRS Tablix row?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with 4 columns and 3 rows, where in the last column I want to merge 3 rows in 1 row for remarks, i tried but nothing found maybe I am missing anything please guide me how to do this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The option to merge cells is fairly limited. Sometimes you have to work around it by combining or nesting objects.

1. Create one table with 2 columns and 1 row and another table with 1 column and 3 rows

[image]

2. Drag the table with 3 rows into the first cell of the other table

[image]

Modifying the size of the tables is a little more tricky with this format, but you can get the desired layout.